# Using 3 Variables for a multitude of data

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

(The title is a bit weird, feel free to change it, I didn't know what to put)
A HTML table will be a history of the last 5 things in a MySQL table, when the first row is loaded, it is stored in a variable for the first row in the HTML table, then the next MYSQL row is loaded/fetched and the second row in the HTML table is then changed to the second row of the MYSQL Table.

Example:

```
for each row:
$username = row["username"]
$name = row["name"]
```

End Result should be in the HTML table:
These are using the above variables, and I need them to be all different data according to the last 5 tables in the MySQL Table

Username   Name
One        Name1   (MySQL Row 1)
Two        Name2   (MySQL Row 2)
Three      Name3   (MySQL Row 3)
Four       Name4   (MySQL Row 4)

Code so far:

```
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare("SELECT * FROM history ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5");
$stmt->execute();



foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    $username = $row['username'];
    $gamemode = $row['gamemode'];
    $winnings = $row['won'];
}
```

Comment: Why do you need variables? `$row` contains the data you need, so just use that.

Comment: For instance, the table will be a history of the last 5 things in a mysql table, when the first row is loaded, it is stored in a variable for the first row in the HTML table, then the next MYSQL row is loaded / fetched and the second row in the HTML table is then changed to the second row of the MYSQL Table.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. I suggest, you provide the last 5 table rows (with field names and field values), then refer yourself to the field names and the field values in order to describe your problem better.

Comment: Updated the question, it should help a little more.

Comment: Thanks. But why do you present two tables? What's the difference btw. them?

Comment: Just present your mysql table (last 5 records) and then present also the html table which you want to have as a result.

Comment: I've explained it and edited it, It's quite simple really, all i need to do is use the same variables but each time they're used they have different data the next time, so that the end result will be all the 5 MySQL rows but in a HTML Table.

Comment: Rows don't "change". Normally you loop over the data and *emit* a row of the table with the correct values. The complete HTML response should have all of that specified in long form. Variables are pointless unless you use them for something.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using the [PDOStatement::fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) method. I suggest you to avoid building html code (like a html table) from php. Feel free to ask anything.

```
<?php
// Create a PDO instance as db connection to a MySQL db.
$dbConnection = new PDO(
        'mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=demo;charset=utf8'
        , 'user'
        , 'pass'
        , array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE,
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => TRUE
        )
);

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM history ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5';

$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare($sql);
$executed = $stmt->execute();

/*
 * Fetch the result set in form of an array.
 * It's used later to build the html table.
 * 
 *  Array
 *  (
 *      [0] => Array
 *          (
 *              [username] => one
 *              [name] => name1
 *          )
 *  
 *      [1] => Array
 *          (
 *              [username] => two
 *              [name] => name2
 *          )
 *  
 *      [2] => Array
 *          (
 *              [username] => three
 *              [name] => name3
 *          )
 *      ...
 *      [4] => Array
 *          (
 *              [username] => five
 *              [name] => name5
 *          )
 *  )
 */
$resultset = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// Just for testing. Delete this in the end.
echo '<pre>' . print_r($resultset, TRUE) . '</pre>';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />

        <title>Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Username</td>
                <td>Name</td>
            </tr>
            <?php
            // Loop through the resultset array and build each html row.
            foreach ($resultset as $row) {
                $username = $row['username'];
                $name = $row['name'];
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $username; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $name; ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep the code as close as you have it, you could use arrays to store the data, like this:

```
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare("SELECT * FROM history ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5");
$stmt->execute();

$usernames = array();
$gamemodes = array();
$winnings = array();

foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    $usernames[] = $row['username'];
    $gamemodes[] = $row['gamemode'];
    $winnings[] = $row['won'];
}
```

Then, you could access them like this:

```
echo $usernames[1]; // Second name
```