# Possible to reduce complexity of fetching and displaying data?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

What I'm doing with the following code is fetching data from a table via PHP in order to display the data on a website.

```
$stri = "SELECT a, b, c, d, e, f FROM table";
$stat = $conn->prepare($stri);

if ($stat->execute()) {
  while ($resu = $stat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    foreach ($resu as $key=>$value) {
      echo $value . "<br>";
    }
    echo "<br><br>";
  }
}
```

However, it seems redundant to use two loops. Is there not a more efficient way to accomplish the same thing while allowing each item of each row to be handled independently?

I plan to do something like the following with it which is why I need to be able to handle the items independently.

```
if ($stat->execute()) {
  while ($row = $stat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<div class="row">';
    foreach ($row as $key=>$value) {
      echo '<div class=' .$key. '>';
      if (empty($value)) echo '---<br>';
      else echo $value;
      echo '</div>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
  }
}
```

Comment: It does not seem redundant to me. In what way do you think this seems redundant?

Comment: @blubear are the two loops absolutely necessary to handle each item of each row independently?

Comment: Well sort of if you choose to use fetch method. If you choose to use fetchAll method like the answers below then you'll have one loop. In any case, I do not see how your code is redundant compared to the answers below. It is an extra loop caused by your choice of using fetch.

Comment: You're going to need to loop over to get each pairing. You could set empty values to `---<br>` in the mysql.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101564/mysql-coalesce-equivalent-for-empty-values

Comment: @blubear so one less loop wouldn't increase performance/be a benefit in comparison to `fetchAll`?

Comment: I think the difference would be negligible, and I think you should not over think it. You can always profile your app if it's slow.

Answer (score 2):

> However, it seems redundant to use two loops.

I cannot get what does it mean, but in all it's quite possible to reduce the complexity. For this you need to use PDO in the full force, not as a just a substitution for mysql_query(). A separation of concerns would also help

Get your data first in the form of array

```
$sql = "SELECT a, b, c, d, e, f FROM table";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

and then display it, somewhere inside the *HTML part* of the page

```
<?php foreach ($data as $row): ?>
    <div class="row">
    <?php foreach ($row as $key=>$value): ?>
        <div class="<?=$key?>">
        <?php if (!$value): ?>
            ---<br>
        <?php else ?>
            <?=$value?>
        <?php endif ?>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: i actually just implemented this. first fetching the data, formatting it, and storing it as a variable, and then later displaying it. :) but what wasn't PDO about my initial implementation?

Answer (score 1):

```
function checking($val)
{
    if(empty($val))
    {
        echo "---<br>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo $val;
    }
}
$stri = "SELECT a, b, c, d, e, f FROM t";

try
{
    $stat = $conn->prepare($stri);
    $stat->execute();
    $results = $stat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach ($results as $key=>$value) 
    {
      echo implode('',array_map("checking",$value));
      echo "<br><br>";
    }

}
catch(Exception $e)
{
     error_log($e->getMessage());
}
```

I do a little bit changed of your code.  Instead of use if to catch error, I prefer to use try catch method.

Comment: i don't want to enjoin them in a single string because i plan on inserting certain HTML around each element

Comment: @Anthony After you build the `$results` array as Deno showed you, you can use it outside the try-catch block. You'll loop through it - same as Deno - and build your html structures using the array items as you wish. Write this after `$results = ...`, in order to see the array structure on screen: `echo '<pre>' . print_r($results, TRUE) . '</pre>';`.

Comment: @aendeerei thanks i will try that. i edited my question. i'm not sure if you saw that. i believe i need to treat the items independently

Comment: @Anthony Yes, I see it now. I wrote an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46817253/using-3-variables-for-a-multitude-of-data/46818298#46818298). Exactly as Deno, I recommended using `fetchAll` to build the resultset. You'll see there that I applied a separation of the fetching codes from the html codes. In my oppinion, fetchAll() is more elegant when fetching multiple records. You can fetch with fetch() too, of course. P.S: I never use `while` in my codes, but that's just me, beeing afraid of meeting infinite loops again :-)